# How to handle versions and settings to a Xamarin.Forms Android app correct?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.**Forms** **Android** app that stores and loads parameters with Application.Current.Properties:
E.g.:

```
Application.Current.Properties["Key"] ="Value";
```

If a new version is created, the app has to be tested by some test users.
For this case, the app has to be installed in parallel to the actual (productive) version.
The parameters then have to be re-entered and stored for the test.

As soon, as the app is tested, it has to be updated productive **whereby the stored parameters have to be adopted**.
Note: The app has to be installed manually (no store in place).

To the android project (in .Forms) there are many settings...
E.G.
Application name
Package name
Version number
Version name

The technical version of the app (e.g. 6 / 7 / and so on) is hard coded in the app (and submitted to a web service that checks the version).
The text to the App Icon (e.g. Appx V7) is set in SplashScreen.cs (as the app use a splashscreen at startup)
(`Activity(Label = "Appx V7"...)`

For the **test** version, I change the "Package name" in the project settings (the result is, that the app is installed **in parallel** to the already installed version what is the goal)

**Questions:**

1. What exactly is the setting, which defines, that an App is **replaced**
   and the already stored parameters are **adopted**?
2. What is the influence of "version number" and "version name" in this context?

**Update to my question (clarification based on the answer from Junior Jiang):**
Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it don’t fully answer my question (maybe the question was misleading, therefore this clarification).
The main question was, which setting(s) triggers, that an already installed app is UPDATED and the already stored data ARE adopted.
As I wrote, I change the “Package name” to create a TEST version (with another package name, the app is installed in parallel and already stored data are NOT adopted (what is CORRECT for the TEST version).
If the app then has been tested, I have to create a new .apk (from the tested version) that the productive users can install and that has to be UPDATE the already installed version, whereby the stored data HAVE to be adopted.
Actually, I change back the “Package name” to the package name of the productive used (installed) version and that seems to work (but is not really nice, especially as I have done the mistake to name the prod .apk with the (now old) version (appx.V6).
**Is the only way to update the app and adopt the stored data to use the SAME  SAME “Package name” (that the installed version had) or is there another (better) solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have to replace my app in a customer project (in the near time), I have checked the behavior and defined the following approach now **for exactly my case** (may be wrong for your case):
**Manifest:**

[[image: Project properties1]

- "Application name" **( 1 )** is not changed
- "Package name" **( 1 )** to the productive installed app version (unfortunately) is set to AppName.**V6**
  => If I could start again, I would name it **.prod** (without version)
- I don't use/change the "Version number" and the "Version name" **( 3 )**

**Process steps:**
[image: Process steps]

**(A) - (My) Starting position:**

- To the productive installed app version, the "Package name" was set to AppName.**V6**
  As I wrote above, this was a mistake (I should have named in .prod instead), but... it now **is** installed with .V6, so I can't go back...)

**(B) - Create new test version:**

- Change the the label text (showed text to Icon) to the new version (in the example **V7**)
- Rename the "Package name" **( 2** ) and **( 2.1 )** to AppName.**whatever**.
  This "triggers", that the App is installed in parallel to the already installed version and the already stored parameters are **not** adopted
- The app is installed on the mobiles of the test users and tested: Changes are done in the app if needed (without to change the manifest data)

**(C) - The app is approved by the testers:**

- All tests are done successful, the app is ready to go productive...

**(D) - Create new version for prod update:**

- Re change the "Package name" **( 2 )** and **( 2.1 )** to AppName.**V6**
  As the installed version (unfortunately) have this "Package name" and the App only will be **replaced**, if this package name ist used for the update.
- This way, the .apk is generated with AppName.**V6**-signed.apk (what is logical wrong, as the real version in the example is **V7**)
- Therefore, I change the name to the .apk after generation manually (in windows explorer) to the correct name (in the example: AppName.**V7**-signed.apk)
  Note: The name of the .apk seems not to have any technical impact. This way, I easily can save versions and versions also can be stored in the user mobile devices...

**(E) - Install new Version:**
The new version is installed on the user mobiles,
thereby **( F )**:

- The already installed app it **replaced**
- Already stored parameters are **adopted**
- The text to the Icon changes to AppName **V7**

This is a description, how **I** do it now for **my** case.
As I wrote above, If I would be able to go back, I would name the "Package name":

- AppName.**Prod** (for the productive app version)
  and
- AppName.**Test** (for the test version(s))

I hope, this helps somebody...
Feel free to post a better solution, if you have one...

Answer (score 0):

About **[Application.Current.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary)** : *The Properties dictionary uses a string key and stores an object value.*

> The `Application` subclass has a static `Properties` dictionary which can be used to store data, in particular for use in the `OnStart`, `OnSleep`, and `OnResume` methods. This can be accessed from anywhere in your Xamarin.Forms code using `Application.Current.Properties`.

It has nothing to do with versions and settings for Android app . So this will not affect the *version number* and *version name* in Android app .

> 1.What exactly is the setting, which defines, that an App is replaced and the already >stored parameters are adopted?
>
> 2.What is the influence of "version number" and "version name" in this context?

[This Version value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#version-the-application) of *version number* and *version name* is stored in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file .

- **Version Number** – An integer value (used internally by Android and the application) that represents the version of the application. Most applications start out with this value set to 1, and then it is incremented with each build. This value has no relationship or affinity with the version name attribute (see below). Applications and publishing services should not display this value to users. This value is stored in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file as `android:versionCode`.
- **Version Name** – A string that is used only for communicating information to the user about the version of the application (as installed on a specific device). The version name is intended to be displayed to users or in Google Play. This string is not used internally by Android. The version name can be any string value that would help a user identify the build that is installed on their device. This value is stored in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file as `android:versionName`.

You can modify them in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file as follow :

[image]

**In addition** , if want to get them in Forms , can use **[DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution)** to do .

Create a **IAppVersionAndBuild** interface :

```
public interface IAppVersionAndBuild {  
    string GetVersionNumber();  
    string GetBuildNumber();  
}
```

Create the implement method class(*VersionAndBuild_Android*) in Android solution :

```
using Android.Content.PM;  
using VersionAndBuildNumber.DependencyServices;  
using VersionAndBuildNumber.Droid.DependencyServices;  
using Xamarin.Forms;  
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(VersionAndBuild_Android))]  
namespace AppOne.Droid.DependencyServices {  
    public class VersionAndBuild_Android: IAppVersionAndBuild {  
        PackageInfo _appInfo;
        public VersionAndBuild_Android() {  
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;  
            _appInfo = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);  
        }  
        public string GetVersionNumber() {  
            return _appInfo.VersionName;  
        }  
        public string GetBuildNumber() {  
            return _appInfo.VersionCode.ToString();
        }  
    }  
}
```

Last in **ContentPage** :

```
string versionName = DependencyService.Get<IAppVersionAndBuild>().GetVersionNumber();  
string versionNumber = DependencyService.Get<IAppVersionAndBuild>().GetBuildNumber();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it don’t fully answer my question. Maybe the question was misleading. Therefore, I have added a clarification at the end of my question above.

Comment: @FredyWenger Thanks for adding a clarification, I will re-check that :-)

Comment: @FredyWenger In general , use the same **PACKAGE NAME** should be the recommanded way . You also can use different package name to install two different apps in mobile .Here we need to notice the updating problem . If using different package name , that will not keep the app updated with the same package . Therefore , same package name also will keep the application be updated with the same data infomation .

Comment: Jiang: That's exactly, what I do and what I have described in my "solution". Thanks for the agreement